# Why am I getting mobile version of page when using WebClient for .NET?

Tags: vb.net, httpwebrequest, webclient

when I use `WebClient.DownloadString` method, the string returned is for the mobile version of a page while I want the desktop version instead. Is it possible to control the request to get the full desktop version instead. Thanks!

Comment: We don't know, depends on how the site is configured. Compare a request from the browser to a request from the WebClient. Most likely the site bases its response on the user agent request header.

Comment: Thanks, controlling he user agent request header is what I was looking for, dont know if you want to post this as an answer so I can accept your solution